# What does quȩ mean, and what does an e with cedilla mean?

Tags: word-request, diacritics

While translating a bit of Bellarmine's Controversies, a work from the end of the 16th century, I came across this sentence: "nam aliquando solemus vocare signa practica omnia illa, quȩ referuntur ad opus, sive mediatè, sive immediatè;..." I tried to google it, but I only found more examples.
Here is the link to the print book:
https://digitale.bibliothek.uni-halle.de/vd16/content/pageview/4150779
It is in the first column, Just above the C quart.

Thank you!

Comment: This is called the e caudata.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It stands for “quae”, here the nominative plural neuter of the relative pronoun.

Comment: Wait, but why? The same text uses *quæ* a short while later.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel. The typographer seems to use the shorter form in this already quite crowded line, and the longer form when the word-spacing is more generous. E.g. quae praeter a few lines further down.